# java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm 

Tags: view, jsf-2, managed-bean

I used **view** scope for bean class.
when i run my application i got the error (JSF2.0,Richfaces3.3.3).

If i use session scope, the following code works fine.

**sample.jsp**

```
<f:view>
   <html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
         <h:form id="sampleForm" binding="#{Sample.initForm}">
            <h:outputText value="This is sample form"/>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>  
</f:view>
```

**Sample.java**

```
package com.sample;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;

@ManagedBean(name="Sample")
@ViewScoped
public class Sample implements Serializable
{
    private HtmlForm initForm;   

    public HtmlForm getInitForm()
    {
        System.out.println("Sample initilaized....");       
        return initForm;
    }

public void setInitForm(HtmlForm initForm)
{
    this.initForm = initForm;
}
}
```

After executing this code, i got the following error

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:293)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:167)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:123)
com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:155)
javax.faces.application.StateManagerWrapper.writeState(StateManagerWrapper.java:143)
org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.writeState(AjaxStateManager.java:57)
com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:225)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
```

Help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm
> ```

The [`HtmlForm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlForm.html) is indeed not [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). You have 2 options:

1. Just don't bind the form component to the view scoped bean at all. There are definitely other ways to achieve the functional requirement for which you thought that binding the form component would be the right solution.
2. Make the property `transient` like so

   ```
   private transient HtmlForm initForm;
   ```

   This way the property will be skipped upon (de)serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i used 'transient' type for all managed bean class. eventhough i got the same error.

Comment: Either the code isn't been rebuilt, or the error is actually not the same (concerns a different class, for example).